# Full name from ldap

Tags: authentication-authorization

Does any know how I can pull the full name of a user from ldap and store it in drupal when a user logs in? Currently the ldap module only store the userid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LDAP](https://drupal.org/project/ldap) module does solve this problem... LDAP user module which comes with ldap module is used to relate, provision (create), and synchronize attributes of LDAP user entries and Drupal users.

Find more documentation related to [LDAP user module](https://drupal.org/node/1685352). For configuration see [Ldap User Configuration.](https://drupal.org/node/1686842)

Comment: I want to make sure it does not synchronize changes back to ldap.